# killall on ubuntu not working as expected finding process name

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

```
user@server:~$ ps fax | grep goh_launcher
11552 pts/2    S+     0:00              \_ grep --color=auto goh_launcher
 4273 ?        S      1:41 /usr/bin/php -q /usr/local/bin/goh_launcher.php

user@server:~$ killall -i goh_launcher.php
goh_launcher.php: nessun processo trovato

user@server:~$ killall -i goh_launcher.ph
Terminare goh_launcher.ph(4273)? (s/N)
```

Why looking for "goh_launcher.php" does not work, while removing the last "p" makes it work?

This is an Ubuntu LTS 12.04 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `killall` manpage:

> -e, --exact
>                 Require an exact match for very long names. **If a command name is
>                 longer  than  15  characters,  the  full name may be unavailable
>                 (i.e. it is swapped out).** In this case, killall will kill every-
>                 thing that matches within the first 15 characters. With -e, such
>                 entries are skipped.  killall prints a message for each  skipped
>                 entry if -v is specified in addition to -e,

I believe your first command exceeds that character limit by 1 character.

Comment: Got it. I've never been able to understand exactly WHAT was the "command name" referred in that entry, and I missed to link the dots. Thanks.